# Win32 , WndProc, and parent-child windows

Tags: winapi, wndproc

I'm developing in C code that uses the Win32 Api to create multiple windows. 
I used `createWindow` twice - to create parent and child windows. 
I have a message loop

```
while ( GetMssage (&msg, NULL,0,0)){
.
translate
dispatch
. 
}
```

But I only get the `WND_Proc` function called once, instead of twice for each of the windows.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you actually seeing a successful HWND result from CreateWindow()?  We'd probably need to see some actual failing code to give any useful help.

Comment: Note that the WM_CREATE message actually is sent to the WndProc during the lifetime of the CreateWindow() call - so if you're setting a breakpoint in the debugger don't step over the CreateWindow() and THEN expect to see a break in your WndProc...

Comment: Some suggestions to improve your question: correct the spelling of GetMessage, correct the capitalization of CreateWindow, and please be more specific on what messages you expect to receive.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you should expect your WndProc to receive a single WM_CREATE message for each window created *of the window class for which the WndProc is registered*.

Your WndProc will not receive a WM_CREATE for a window you create of a different class (like the standard Windows UI controls, for example), even if it is a direct child of a window of the WndProc's class. If you gave us some more specifics on what you are trying to accomplish we could provide suggestions or workarounds.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844101/displaying-a-bitmap-on-a-button-class-window-in-win32) may also shed some more light on your situation.

Comment: Hi - I am not talking about the WM_CREATE message, but rather
about general message suchas WM_KEYDOWN : I want to deal with them in both windows. I asked another question with some code examples as well right now.

Comment: @dan: you may have wanted to add a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708499/createwindow-win32-api-problem-only-parent-window-gets) to your other question as well )